# Um BOTÃO para salvar dados de todos os forms!

Tags: javascript, html, html5

tenho um formulário extenso com algumas abas e em cada aba existe um form com método "post".
Gostaria de criar um BOTÃO "finalizar" na última aba que salvasse todos os dados inseridos em todos os form do formulário, como faço?

Obs: Devido o formulário ser mt grande, não tem como colocar aqui tds os códigos por isso irei resumir e caso precise de algum código eu acrescento na pergunta.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Os form das abas estão assim:

```
<form action="/Pasta/SalvarInquerito" method="post" id="FormInquerito"></form>
<form action="/Autor/Salvar" id="formAutor" method="post"></form>
<form action="/Pasta/SalvarCrime" method="post" id="FormCrime"></form>
<form action="/Filhos/Salvar" id="formFilho" method="post"></form>
<form method="post" id="PericiaForm" action="/Pasta/SalvarPericia"></form>
<form action="/Pasta/SalvarVitima" method="post" id="FormVitima"></form>
```

O botão que eu uso em cada aba para salvar os dados inseridos na aba:

```
<button type="submit"
                id="btnSalvar"
                form="FormVitima"
                class="btnSalvarGreen">
            SALVAR
</button>
```

Comment: Precisa mesmo ter vários forms? Independente de quantas sessões você pode deixar todas num só form já que quer salvar todas de uma vez só e não uma de cada vez.

Comment: Acho que você está procurando esse método [HTMLFormElement.submit()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit). No caso seria um botão externo aos formulários que chamaria esse método para cada um dos forms? Confirme para que possa apresentar uma resposta para mim ficou um pouco vago.

Comment: @AugustoVasques Sim exatamente isso!

Comment: @MizrainPhelipeSá, já responderam e a resposta me parece adequada.

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que uma das maneiras seria utilizando um javascript simples (e se precisar eu posso escrever um exemplo em jQuery).
 No botão que você criou coloque um evento *onclick* com um nome de função e altere o tipo de *submit* para *button* para que o controle da DOM fique no JS. Assim como no exemplo abaixo:

```
<input type="button" id="btnSalvar" class="btnSalvarGreen" value="SALVAR" onclick="salvarForms()" />
```

No código javascript, faça uma ação *submit* para cada formulário que você desejar baseado em seu ID:

```
salvarForms = function(){
   document.getElementById("formInquerito").submit();
   document.getElementById("formCrime").submit();
   .
   .
   .
}
```

Pronto! Provavelmente você conseguirá salvar múltiplos forms dessa maneira. Depois me fala se deu certo, ok?

Comment: Certo, vou testar aqui walther!

Comment: testei seu código, fiz exatamente igual porém quando clico da esse erro no console: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'submit' of null
    at salvarForms (Arquivos:588)
    at HTMLInputElement.onclick (Arquivos:492)

Comment: Você fez o check se os campos dos formulários estão preenchidos?

Comment: Sim, estão preenchidos, porém esta dando esse erro.

Comment: Se está dando o erro `Cannot read property 'submit' of null` é porque quando faz o `getElementById()` o `id` passado como parâmetro não está sendo encontrado no documento provavelmente o `id` está escrito errado.